# Login Failed with eWAY Recurring Payment Processor

Tags: recurring-contributions, eway

I have installed the [eWay Recurring Payment Processor](https://civicrm.org/extensions/eway-recurring-payment-processor) (version 1.2) in my site and it processes one-off payments fine. However when I processes a recurring payment I get the following error: "9010: Failed to create managed customer - result (faultcode, faultstring) is (soap:Client, Login failed. )".

When I contacted eWay regarding this error they gave the response that I was sending the request to an incorrect URL (https://www.eway.com.au/gateway/managedpayment/CreateCustomer).  Is anyone else getting this error? If this extension is out of date is there a new one?

Comment: 1.2 is the latest & there are others on that version.

There are some notes on the README - https://github.com/ChrisChinchilla/CiviCRM-eWay-recurring-payment-processor which covering setting up an api password

Comment: I have followed those instructions and no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had the same issue when setting up recurring payments for the first time. This is how we resolved it. Note: This is for Australia only.

1. Login to MyeWay and create an API Key and password.
2. In CiviCRM, modify or create an eWay recurring payment processor with the following:
   **Username:** your usual eWay username (ie. email address).
   **Password:** The new API password you just created in Step 1.
   **Site URL:** https://www.eway.com.au/gateway_cvn/xmlpayment.asp
   **Recurring Payments URL:** https://www.eway.com.au/gateway/ManagedPaymentService/managedCreditCardPayment.asmx?WSDL

Also to confirm we are using the 1.2 version of the eWay Recurring Payment Processor and it does not require any update to get it working.

Comment: Perfect. This worked for me too. Thanks!

Comment: Also need to NOT use test payments but use test credit cards on the live payments (https://go.eway.io/s/article/Test-Credit-Card-Numbers).